# Input mask with plain value

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What's the best way to create a input mask that keeps the original value (i.e. not masked one) in the input ?

For example:

let's use the mask `99999-999`, and the number `58398000`.

What I want is the number to be displayed as:

`58398-000` and input's really value to be `58398000`.

I need this because the validation counts the number of digits and check if there's only digits.

And also the mask should appear when the page load with input's value setted.

Tried this one:
http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#inputmask

The jasny's plugin has 2 issues:

- First is that the input's value has the separator, for example `input.val() == "58398-000"`
- Second, when the page loads with value setted the mask isn't updated.
  For example:
  `<input type="text" value="58398000" class="form-control" data-mask="99999-999">`, in this case the mask isn't displayed.

P.S: Using bootstrap and jQuery

Comment: the jasny bootstrap didn't worked?

Comment: @YannChabot, updated the question.

Comment: Why not strip non-numeric characters before passing through validation?

Comment: Do you send your form by ajax? Or you send it using submit input?

Comment: @J.Titus the valiador receives the `$request->all()` (It's Laravel's default validation system), although it's possibe looks bad, do you agree ?

Comment: @YannChabot, Not Ajax, submit input...

Comment: @VictorAurélio Can you modify `$request` before it gets sent to the validator? (Assuming `$request` is where the form data is held)

Comment: you should do a validation before you submit using jQuery and make sure the field value is formatted as you'd like. Or you could add a value to your input that would be data-real-value or something like that, and you could format this onKeyUp or keyDown in the field. And then, on validation switch the value of the input before you submit the form?

Comment: @J.Titus, `$request` is a instance of `Request` I think that I can't modifify  it direct but sure there's a way, but not looks good.

Comment: @YannChabot, is this the best way ?

Comment: And about the second problem ?

Comment: @VictorAurélio To me, it is the best way since it is only front-end validation anyways, you'll have to do back-end validation also before inserting value into database to make sure it respects what you expect it to be (somebody could send value with his own script). So yes, front-end validation for a front-end problem is the best way. then, you will have to do back-end validation also anyways so it's a good way.

Comment: @YannChabot, Thanks, can you write a answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Sure ! I will write it give me 5 min :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a validation before you submit using jQuery and make sure the field value is formatted as you'd like. Or you could add a value to your input that would be data-real-value or something like that, and you could format this onKeyUp or keyDown in the field.

You could either use

```
$('#yourSubmitButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.prevenDefault();
    //Your validation
    if (//Form is valid){
       $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Required documentation:

jQuery keyup -> https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

jQuery keydown -> https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

jQuery submit -> https://api.jquery.com/submit/

**N.B: Do not forget to do your back-end validation also to make sure that people surely used your form before you use the received data in your database or anything.**

Comment: And the second problem of jasny's plugin described in question ?

Comment: You mean when the page load? Then you can set the default value exactly the way you want when you set the value attribute